# PHP OOP Approaach

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm currently studying and writing codes in PHP with OOP approach. Am I on the right track? Will try to use MVC system when I'm used to this approach. Can you tell me what i need to improve or what to read like articles, documentation or guides when using MVC approach? Thank you!

**database.class.php**

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $db;
    private $cfg;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cfg = include('conf/config.php');

        try{
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->cfg['host']
            . ";dbname=" . $this->cfg['dbname'],
            $this->cfg['username'],
            $this->cfg['password'],
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
        }
        catch(PDOEsception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'host'      =>  'localhost',
    'dbname'    =>  'test',
    'username'  =>  'root',
    'password'  =>  ''
];
?>
```

**user.service.php**

```
<?php
require_once('class/database.class.php');

class UserService
{
    private $dbh;
    private $db;

    private $username;
    private $password;

    private $_user;

    public function __construct($username, $password)
    {
        $this->dbh = new Database();
        $this->db = $this->dbh->getConnection();
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        try
        {
            $user = $this->checkInformation();
            if ($user) {
                $this->_user = $user;
                return $user;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function checkInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            $checkUsername = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = :uname');
            $checkUsername->execute(
                [
                    ':uname' => $this->username
                ]
            );
            if ($checkUsername->rowCount() > 0) {
                $userData = $checkUsername->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $hashedpwd = $userData['pwd'];
                $verify = password_verify($this->password, $hashedpwd);
                if ($verify) {
                    return $userData;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a site for code reviews

Comment: Also, as a hint: this abomination has nothing to do with good OOP and even less with MVC (you do not even seem to understand what it is). If you want to improve, learning about dependency injection and stopping to make "database wrapper" would be a good start.